# What's the difference between $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']?

Tags: php, apache

I have a php framework and I used `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` to optimize portability. That way I don't need to manually configure the path anymore.

```
$this->base_url = str_replace('index.php', '', 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

But I noticed that `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` returns the exact same string. So, what's the difference? How should I choose between them?

Comment: The manual is more than self explanatory, http://in2.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php, however your script may be limited by number of factors, a web host may have set up your environment in such a way that you may not be able to see the actual filesystem path for scriptname index, btw, I would rather do RTFM, followed by googling, you learn more by doing it yourself :-)

Comment: I read this many times before asking here. I wouldn't have asked here otherwise.

Comment: please don't feel offended by my comment, I was just adding to what manual says, glad to see you got your answer, I am more of a do it myself guy, mostly find my answer in said fashion

Comment: i understand. but this is kind of a specific question, not easily found on google. but what were you saying about problems with webhosting? what differences the $_SERVER variables can present based on server configurations?

Comment: not the PHP_SELF but may be SCRIPT_NAME, as of now I am myself stuck in a situation, I will check this later with `chroot`-ed environment

Comment: you're welcome to post your findings here. it will be very helpful (:

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Difference

```
http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/3e38d.php/test
```

Script name is absolute path to file.

`PHP_SELF` is script you're currently in (along with "path" after `.php`)

It's like `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` and `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`

```
http://sandbox.phpcode.eu./g/f5093.php

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/f5093.php
```

spot one difference

Comment: this was actually very helpful (:

Comment: "Script name is absolute path to file." - `SCRIPT_NAME` is root-relative, not _absolute. `SCRIPT_FILENAME` contains an absolute path (although this is not necessarily the same file as `SCRIPT_NAME`).

Answer (score 8):

```
SCRIPT_NAME
```

> Contains the current script's path. This is useful for pages which need to point to themselves. The `__FILE__` constant contains the full path and filename of the current (i.e. included) file.

```
PHP_SELF
```

> The filename of the currently executing script, relative to the document root. For instance, `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` in a script at the address `http://example.com/test.php/foo.bar` would be `/test.php/foo.bar`. The `__FILE__` constant contains the full path and filename of the current (i.e. included) file. If PHP is running as a command-line processor this variable contains the script name since PHP 4.3.0. Previously it was not available.

source [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

There is one thing:

Check out `http://www.yoursite.com/example/index.php/dir/test`

in `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/example/index.php/dir/test';`

in `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] == '/example/index.php';`

ETA:
Tried myself

Tried this on localhost
http://127.0.0.1:8887/index.php/dir/test

```
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "<br />";
echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
```

Output is:

```
/index.php/dir/test 
/index.php
```

Comment: note that the example here excludes the file name `index.php` and what goes between it and the server name. in @genesis link it correctly returns `/g/3e38d.php/test` instead of returning only `/test`

Comment: Agreed, it has all directory stuff + script itself.

Comment: now it's correct. just note that the link 'examples' show that same wrong example too :p