# having issues with php_self

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to implement a page where a user enters a comment and it gets displayed right in the same page. The problem i am having is that every time you go to the page there are no comments in the page(there are actually comments).
This is my sceneario i am having:

1. I go to the page and there are no comments, i enter a comment 'hello' and it gets displayed right away.
2. I go to a different page and then i come back to the comments page and there are no comments.(the comment "hello" should be already displayed)
3. I enter a comment "hi" and both comments "hello" and "hi" get displayed

I cant resolve this issue..

This is my code, its pretty long

```
  <?php
 session_start(); //starts or continues the session
 require_once('functions.php'); //needed for some function calls
 error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">

<head>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "functions.js"></script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">      
</head>

<body>

<?php
 GetUserLayout($_SESSION['userId'], $_SESSION['superUser']);

 ?>

    <div id = "shareyouridea_form" class = "post">
      <h1> Share your post</h1>    
      <!-- used for the form -->
      <form id = "idea_form" method = "post"  
        action = "<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>"
    onkeypress = "return DisableEnterKey(event);">
        <table>
      <caption> 
        <strong> 
          <br /> Share post form:
        </strong> 
      </caption>
      <tr class = "spacearound"> <!-- input for bright idea -->
                <td> &emsp;Post: </td>
                <td>
          <textarea form = "idea_form" name = "b_idea" rows = "12" 
          cols = "85" title = "Please describe your product idea" 
          id = "bright_idea" maxlength = "1000"
          onkeypress = 
          "return InputLimiter(event, 'lettersSpacePunctuation');">
          </textarea>
                </td>
              </tr>
    </table>

        <p>
      &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;
      <input type = "reset" value = "Reset" />
      &emsp;&emsp;        
      <input type = "submit" value = "Share Idea!"
        title = "complete form first to submit"
        id = "submit_button"
        name = "add_comment"
                onmousedown = "IsIdeaFormCompleted();" />
    </p>
          </form> <!-- end idea_form -->            
        </div>
  </div> <!-- end of ShareYourIdea_middle -->
  <script>
        DisplayFooter();
 </script>

 <?php
  if(isset($_POST['add_comment'])){ // if add comment was pressed

   // get variables
 $name = $_SESSION['firstName'];
     $empId = $_SESSION['userId'];
     $idea = $_POST['b_idea'];

    // CONNECTING TO OUR DATABASE
$db = mysqli_connect(dbHost, dbUser, dbPassword, dbName);

   if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { //if connection to the database failed
 echo("<p id = 'greatideadescription'>
          Connection to database failed: " .
      mysqli_connect_error($db) . "</p>");
exit("goodbye");
  }  //by now we have connection to the database


// WE WRITE OUR QUERY TO INSERT POST INFO TO DATABASE
 $query = "INSERT INTO posts(postId,empl_Id,post,postDate)
        VALUES('','$empId','$idea',NOW())";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);



  }

 ?>

 <?php
  // WE DO A QUERY TO SHOW ALL COMMENTS IN THE PAGE
 $query = "SELECT firstName,lastName, post,
      date_format((date_add(postDate,interval -7 hour)),'%a, %M, %d, %Y at %I:%i%p' ) as        mydatefield 
      FROM users INNER JOIN posts ON userId = empl_Id
      ORDER BY postDate DESC";

 $result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
 if (!$result) { //if the query failed
    echo("<p id = 'greatideadescription'>
     Error, the query could not be executed: " .
     mysqli_error($db) . "</p>");
    mysqli_close($db);}

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) { //if no rows returned
  echo("<div id = 'blogs'>
          <div id ='name'>
            No posts detected
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='fb-like' data-href='http://jacobspayroll.zxq.net/index/blog.php'   data-send='true' data-width='450' data-show-faces='true'></div>
    ");
  mysqli_close($db); //close the database
  exit("</table></div></form></div></div>
      <script>DisplayFooter();</script></body></html>");
      } //by now we know that we have some products purchases returned
  $numRows = mysqli_num_rows($result); //gets number of rows
  $numFields = mysqli_num_fields($result); //gets number of fields
  //prints the data in the table

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $posted = $row['post'];
  $message = wordwrap($posted,5);
  echo 
    '<div id ="blogs">
        <table id = "blog_id">
          </br>
           <div id = "name">
            <strong>'.$row['firstName'] . '&nbsp;' .$row['lastName'].
          '</strong>
          &nbsp;: ' .$message .
          '<br/> 
          </div>
          <div id ="date">'.
          $row['mydatefield'] . '
          </div>
          <div id ="delete_comment">
            Delete this comment 
          </div>
          <p>
        </table>
    </div>';    
 }
  mysqli_close($db); 

  ?>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the wrong Usage of `PHP_SELF`

```
//You must use  Server and execution environment information `$_SERVER[]`

$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

// For your form action like this
 action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"
```

Comment: at your form action... instead of `$PHP_SELF` it must be `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`

Comment: thanks, but i am still having the same issue.When i first get to that page there is a error saying Error, the query could not be executed, and there are no posts  but i could still post a comment, and once i do. I see all the posts. I want the posts to always show.

Comment: did your data already been submitted and post to database table for `post`

Comment: argghh better check your db if data are been inserted because if its not .. there will be usually no display when you going back to that page..

Comment: it does get inserted because after i enter my comment i see all the posts i posted before. I dont know. Im just really lost right now

Comment: youve better check where your form falls upon the condition of if and else in `INSERTING INTO post`

Comment: insertion only happens when a user presses the button, I think i am doing the isset correctly

Comment: yess that right but what i need you to figure out is whether you post falls in if condition or else condition inside the isset  to determine what error could possible made your data not inserted to your database.

Comment: i figured it out. I wasnt connecting to my database. I will mark this as answered. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

as Kail mentioned you got it wrong but you might want to use `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` instead of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` then you might want to add some script to get GET parameters if you use them for your script(s). If you use PHP_SELF you might have a user link to `script.php/%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert('xss')%3C/script%3E%3Cfoo` might look like `action="script.php/"><script>alert('xss')</script>` or could be a redirect to collect cookies and the alike in other words XSS attack.

[$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] vs $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] vs $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']](http://raptor.hk/_serverphp_self-vs-_serverscript_name-vs-_serverrequest_uri/)

[XSS Woes](http://seancoates.com/blogs/xss-woes)

[What's the difference between $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6719197/1700963)

Comment: Could you elaborate on the advantage of `SCRIPT_NAME`?