# URL prevent href button action php

Tags: php, arrays, url, href

Hi I have a href tag where I order an array values(up to down or down to up),so my problem is that when I click twice in the same button I have no action performed.That because of in my url I have something like that:
When I click for the 1st time on my button the action is done,but I click again on the same button nothing,but when I click 'F5' action the action is done:
Exemple in my URL when I click one time:

```
http://localhost/home/test.php?dir=down&keyword=1
```

The second time I click the URL remains the same but no action is done.it is done when I click on F5.

My hyperlink:

```
echo "<a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?dir=down&keyword=$keywordkey\"><img src=web/images/remove.png /></a>";
```

How can I resolve this ?
Thank you!!!

Comment: Just a word of caution please change `PHP_SELF` to `SCRIPT_NAME`. `PHP_SELF` in the case you are using it for someone could have something like `test.php&lt;script&gt;window.href.location=somebadurl&lt;/script&gt;` and uses a url shortener and gives it to some user and steals user data and what not [What's the difference between $_SERVER\['PHP_SELF'\] and $_SERVER\['SCRIPT_NAME'\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6719197/1700963)

Answer (score 0):

After you click on the button for the first time, you give command to your script to sort it downwards.

Once this action is complete, you still have same command to provide to your script i.e. down

Since it is a same command going to the your code, is does exactly same thus, the results are also same.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what u explain me

Comment: @user222914, Your link in href will not change after simply clicking it so the results are same. You have to change to something like `up`

Comment: Yes I understand when I mix with Up/down all work perfectly,but any way to perform twice 2 up or 2 down on the same button?

Comment: Yes, you can send parameter to your script like `$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?dir=down&times=2&keyword=$keywordkey`

Comment: The problem is that my up/down actions are in a loop foreach,...so the parameter  times will remain the same as before

Comment: @user222914, That you are trying to use, is not a proper way. Please post another another with what you need and where you are stuck.